# Converting a string to a datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Simple question cannot seem to get right.

I have a table with a date in this format `20/09/2012` as `varchar`.

I need to convert to a `datetime`

Tried various solutions but cannot get it right.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `CONVERT(datetime, '2012/09/20 00:00:00', 120)` ? Also for date formatting options you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Store it as a `DATETIME` in the first place ...

Comment: Using `convert(datetime, '20/09/2012', 103)` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `CONVERT` function with style 103 (British/European) seems to work for me:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20) = '20/09/2012'

SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, @input, 103)
```

With this approach, you could convert all your `VARCHAR` dates to their proper datatype - `DATETIME` - and store them as `DATETIME` in the first place ....

See Aaron Bertrand great blog post on [bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) for more background info on why it's really really bad to keep storing dates as `VARCHAR` columns ....